# How can I display the article of a specific user according to the number of views of this article?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains articles posted by users. The structure of the table is like this:

```
id      uid       author       article_name     article     num_views      edit_time
```

`id` is the article id, `uid` is the author id and `num_views` is how many times this article is being viewed.

What I need is to display ONLY the most viewed article according to `uid`

In short , if **`uid`** is **`author id`** and **`article id`** is **`5`** , what I need is to display something like :

```
id     uid     article_name     num_views 
5       1      article title       100
```

I tried to run several queries in Mysql but i could not figure it out , can anyone help please ??

Comment: try `SELECT id, uid, article_name, num_views FROM Articles ORDER BY num_views DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: shouldn't the `uid` be 2 in your example result?

Comment: ELECT id, uid, article_name, num_views FROM Articles WHERE `uid` = '1' ORDER BY num_views DESC LIMIT 1    , this one just done what i need , thank alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most viewed article and its count by each user:

```
SELECT `id`, `uid`, `article_name`, `num_views` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `num_views` IN ( 
    SELECT MAX(`num_views`) FROM table GROUP BY `uid`)
```

For only given uid

```
SELECT `id`, `article_name`, MAX(`num_views`) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `uid` = <user id>
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `id` and `article_name` will match the row with max(num_views) there.

Comment: this query is returning the wrong id(article id) and it is not selecting according to a specific uid.

Comment: @wfareed you need only for one uid ?

Comment: @wfareed  i have included both version

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one entry you should try to sort your query with ORDER BY command and limit it to the one article by LIMIT 1 command.

SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE (some criteria) ORDER BY NUM_VIEWS DESC LIMIT 1.

That should select an article with the most views.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky and if your table gets big it's going to be non-performant, but one way to do this would be:

```
select uid,
group_concat(id order by num_views desc) as most_viewed_id,
group_concat(article_name order by num_views desc) as most_viewed_name,
group_concat(num_views order by num_views desc) as num_views
from yourtable group by uid
```

You'll then have to parse out the first element from each of the group_concat'd fields.

Another way would be to use a join with a subquery, but it can be weird if there's two articles for the same user with the same highest number of views, and also has performance issues:

```
select uid,num_views,id,article,article_name from 
yourtable join 
(select uid,max(num_views) as maxviews from yourtable group by uid) as subtable
using (uid,num_views)
```

Of course at a certain point the best way might be to just iterate over uids with a simple order by query. It's a lot more queries but it can be faster depending on your data. Unfortunately SQL just isn't really set up to do queries like this.